# Plotting results of Groupby DatFrame in PANDAS/Python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I´ve the following Pandas Dataframe (only showing first 10 rows) after having groupedby by indexes "d" and "n".

I want different line plots for each "d", with the x-axis the variable "n", and in the y-axis the "mean" +/- 2 * "std" values.

I also want additional line plot with same axes, but showing different line values for the different "mean" values only.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSFY7.png)
If you could help, much appreciated.

Comment: Please always post code, data, error messages as text on SO, not as a picture. I suggest reading also [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def somefunc(df):
    x = df['n']
    y1 = df['mean']+2*df['std']
    y2 = df['mean']-2*df['std']
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,y1)
    plt.plot(x,y2)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=4, size=(100, 5)),
                    columns=['mean', 'std', 'c', 'd', 'n'])

g = df.groupby('d').apply(somefunc)
```